# Error php mysql code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a catalog page.  I have a php page showing all catalogs types and once I click on a type it fetches all rows that has a relationship to that particular catalog.  That part works, but if a catalog has 0 items and a user clicks on it; it doesn't even get down to showing what catalog that was clicked.

I'm passing the catalog as a parameter to the page that will fetch and display the results.

```
echo '<a href="list.php?Catalog='.$row['CatCode'].'" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'. $row['Count'] .'</span>'. $row['Catelog'] .'</a>';
```

When I click a link that has records it shows up in the url with the right parameter, but ones that don't have any records show nothing up there.

If I go in and add 1 row to that catalog in the database then it works just fine.  It just doesn't work for rows that have 0 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a query gives you back 0 records, there is no $row['CatCode'] etc. Maybe you can show us the query you are running?

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It finally hit me that I was telling it to use the primary key for the table it had to look into for the records instead of using the primary key of the catalog that was clicked.  So it was using null since there was no records in the many-to-many table.  Thanks again for trying to help.